# How to get a unique identifier of geofence in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geofencing

I am new to this geofencing. Can anyone tell me how to get the geofence unique id, to set in the following attribute???

```
window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
     id:             String, //A unique identifier of geofence
     latitude:       Number, //Geo latitude of geofence
     longitude:      Number, //Geo longitude of geofence
     radius:         Number, //Radius of geofence in meters
     transitionType: Number, //Type of transition 1 - Enter, 2 - Exit, 3 - Both
  }
```

Anyone help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the small code snippet to generate unique id with lenght 8.following code to generate unique id.

```
(function() {
     function IDGenerator() {

         this.length = 8;
         this.timestamp = +new Date;

         var _getRandomInt = function( min, max ) {
            return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
         }

         this.generate = function() {
             var ts = this.timestamp.toString();
             var parts = ts.split( "" ).reverse();
             var id = "";

             for( var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i ) {
                var index = _getRandomInt( 0, parts.length - 1 );
                id += parts[index];  
             }

             return id;
         }


     }


     document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var btn = document.querySelector( "#generate" ),
            output = document.querySelector( "#output" );

        btn.addEventListener( "click", function() {
            var generator = new IDGenerator();
            output.innerHTML = generator.generate();

        }, false); 

     });


 })();
```

Markup is

```
<p><button id="generate">Generate</button></p>
<p><code id="output"></code></p>
```

Hope it helps u.

Comment: Thanks. you mean, we can to generate unique id seperately to assign for genfencing????

Comment: ok . can u tell me, we need enable to any google API to achieve geofencing??

Comment: I am not sure as i didn't use this plugin, according to geofencing cordova document No need to enable any google API.

Comment: ok. Do you know using geofencing how to restrict our app to work upto particular kilo meter from the given lattitude and longitude????

Comment: its hard to discuss here, catch me on naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com